# How to Apply Dex to a Two Handed Weapon

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

As the title states I'm looking for Feats, magic, special material, arcytypes or anything besides house rules thay can allow me to apply my Dexterity modifyier to attack rolls while wielding a Two Handed Weapon, like a greatsword for example.

*Bonus points if it also adds it to Damage*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several weapons including ones that are two handed that are usable with the [weapon finesse](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/weapon-finesse-combat-final/) feat. Then if you are allowed to use the unchained rules, an unchained rogue has the ability to add dex to damage for one of these weapons! This allows you to get 1.5x dex as damage!

> At 1st level, a rogue gains Weapon Finesse as a bonus feat. In addition, starting at 3rd level, she can select any one type of weapon that can be used with Weapon Finesse (such as rapiers or daggers). Once this choice is made, it cannot be changed. Whenever she makes a successful melee attack with the selected weapon, she adds her Dexterity modifier instead of her Strength modifier to the damage roll. If any effect would prevent the rogue from adding her Strength modifier to the damage roll, she does not add her Dexterity modifier. The rogue can select a second weapon at 11th level and a third at 19th level.

Some of the two handed weapons I had mentioned are

- [Dueling Sword](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/sword-dueling/) (exotic 1 handed but can be wielded with two hands)
- [Estoc](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/estoc) (exotic 1 handed but can be wielded with two hands)
- [Spiked Chain](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/chain-spiked) or [Bladed Scarf](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/scarf-bladed) (Still exotic)
- [Elven Curved Blade](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/curve-blade-elven/) or [Elven branched spear](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/spear-elven-branched) (exotic, but can be martial for elves)